# WPF two way binding not working on CheckBox

Tags: wpf, checkbox, binding

I can't manage to make my two way binding with the `CheckBox` work.

The `CheckBox` item source is `PRESTAZIONI` and contains a `bool` field called `Check_Status` with default 0.

The Data Binding code (DataClassesDataContext) is generated by the LINQtoSQL drag and drop, so it should be fine. 
It has all the ViewModel parts of this solution [WPF CheckBox TwoWay Binding not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094679/wpf-checkbox-twoway-binding-not-working).

I have this XAML code:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3">
    <ListBox Name ="listPrest" Height="91" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Name="chkPrest" Width="220" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Check_Status, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} ({1})">
                                <Binding Path="Nome" />
                                <Binding Path="Code" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

In the code of the view, I initialize the source of the `CheckBox`es like this:

```
public partial class InsertServiceView : UserControl
{
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    IQueryable<PRESTAZIONI> prest = null;
    public InsertServiceView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UpdatePrestList();
    }

    private void UpdatePrestList()
    {
        if (prest != null)
        {
            foreach (PRESTAZIONI p in prest)
            {
                p.Check_Status = false;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            prest = from p in db.PRESTAZIONI select p;
        }

        listPrest.ItemsSource = prest.ToList();
    }

    private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (prest.Where(p => p.Check_Status == true).Count() == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No selections");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And even if I check the `CheckBox`es this last if keeps returning true.

The one way binding used to work, but I need to update the value of `Check_Status` to all `false` because I use it also in other forms and I want them to be all `false` when I open this one.

I've seen a lot of questions similar to mine and applied all the solutions but still it is not working. 
Any suggestion would be very appreciated.
Sorry for the poor English.

**EDIT:**

The table PRESTAZIONI has a primary key.
This is the code for PRESTAZIONI generated by the drag and drop:

```
protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
        {
            if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
            {
                this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
            }
        }

public partial class PRESTAZIONI : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private bool _Check_Status;

    partial void OnCheck_StatusChanging(bool value);
    partial void OnCheck_StatusChanged();

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Check_Status", DbType="Bit NOT NULL")]
    public bool Check_Status
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Check_Status;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Check_Status != value))
            {
                this.OnCheck_StatusChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Check_Status = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Check_Status");
                this.OnCheck_StatusChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the PRESTAZIONI  class, and how is the Check_Status property defined?

Comment: Confirm that your `PRESTAZIONI` class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and in `Check_Status` property setter has send a `Check_Status` property change notification.

Comment: Not sure that this is your problem, but take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069227/how-do-i-make-my-linq-to-sql-entity-implement-inotifypropertychanged

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really familiar with `IQueryable`, but could it be that your `ToList()` call is generating new instances of `PRESTAZIONI`?

In your save method you are checking the original `IQueryable` instance. It feels like you should be storing the `List` instead and checking that.